# How does a double layer of reverse proxy pass through invalid SSL cert?

Tags: ssl, https, reverse-proxy, haproxy, kong

I have the following server setup:

```
                 +----------+        +-----------+
                 |          |        |           |
internet ----->  |   Kong   | -----> |  HAProxy  | -----> backend servers
                 |          |        |           |
                 +----------+        +-----------+
```

- [Kong](https://konghq.com/) is set port 443 binding with **a valid SSL cert**
- [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) is set up with port 443 binding and a redirect from port 80 to 443

Now I just found that the SSL cert installed in the HAProxy expired. However, it's not visible through the internet because they access through Kong and Kong has a valid SSL cert. Accessing the HAProxy directly gives a `SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired` error. What is the explanation for this? How does the first layer of reverse proxy's SSL cert suppress the error on the second layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the first layer of reverse proxy's SSL cert suppress the error on the second layer?

The clients create a SSL connection to Kong and will only check the certificate from Kong. Kong creates an independent SSL connection to HAProxy and should check the certificate from HAProxy. Then only the application payload gets passed through between client and server via Kong and HAProxy, but not any SSL related information.

> How does the first layer of reverse proxy's SSL cert suppress the error on the second layer?

It does not suppress anything. **There is no mechanism to pass thru SSL errors at the application level**. Proper validation of the certificate from HAProxy by Kong **should lead to a connection close**, i.e. not forwarding any of the application data between client and server. But **if the certificate is not  properly validated by Kong then certificate errors will not be noticed** and the application data will be forwarded between client and server. The **client will not notice anything since it sees only the certificate by Kong**.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Ok, understood your answer at a high level. But isn't Kong is an "application" by itself and hence how can it skip the validation as it forwards the data?

Comment: @yonasstephen: Certificate validation is an extra step. While applications should better verify certificates, it can often be explicitly disabled. And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585338/3081018) seems to suggest that Kong even by default does not verify certificates, at least not in older versions.